# Where Can I ask questions about Ebook Readers?

Tags: discussion

About the functionality of Ebook readers like Kobo and Kindle, there are really few non-obsolete forums on internet, can I ask those questions here?

Answer (score 2):

Mobileread has a forum dedicated to the largest number of current and old reading devices. http://www.mobileread.com/forums/index.php You can ask lots of questions there.

Comment: Thanks a lot , yet I love this website, it's too hard to communicate in old type forums , I found out that there are some similar questions like what i needed to ask